# Insert session variable into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I am new to PHp and I am trying to enter details into my database. I am trying to enter an eventname- which the user enters (POST) and the username of the logged in user.

I have created sessions to store users usernames, the code i have is

```
$eventname=$_POST['eventname'];
$myusername = $_SESSION['myusername']

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_nameVALUES('','$eventname','$_SESSION['myusername'])");

echo "You have been added to the event";
```

Its the $sql statement which is giving the error? any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks all!

Comment: It would be best if you also gave the error message! It looks like a syntax error from where I'm standing. pollirata and Micheal have both answered the question in depth.

Comment: Your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several potential problems here.

First, you have not escaped `eventname` against SQL injection. We assume hopefully that `myusername` is already safe.  If it has not been previously filtered, also use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$_SESSION['myusername']`.

```
$eventname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['eventname']);

// Then you need space before VALUES and are missing a closing quote on $_SESSION['myusername'], which should be in {}
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('','$eventname','{$_SESSION['myusername']}')");
```

Finally, in order for the statement to work, it assumes you have exactly three columns in `$tbl_name`.  You should be explicit about the columns used.  Substitute the correct column names for `colname1, event_name, username`.

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name (colname1, event_name, username) VALUES('','$eventname','{$_SESSION['myusername']}')");
```

The exact locations of SQL syntax errors will be revealed to you with some basic error checking via `mysql_error()`.

```
$sql = mysql_query(<your insert statement>);
if (!$sql) {
  echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: I have made the changes you listed the error message states unexpected T_VARIABLE, i know this is a syntax error.

Comment: If you have unexpected `T_VARIABLE` on the `$eventname` line, you probably have a syntax error on the line _before_ that, like a missing `;`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `'` on your insert statement. Try this

```
INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('','$eventname','$_SESSION['myusername']')
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it help you...

```
$eventname=$_POST['eventname'];
$myusername = $_SESSION['myusername'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES('','$eventname','".$_SESSION['myusername'])."'");

echo "You have been added to the event";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between `$tbl_name` and `VALUES`, and indeed a `'` after `$_SESSION['myusername']`.

And look up SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around the key in your `$_SESSION` array:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('', '$eventname', '$_SESSION[myusername])");
```